# My date is displayed as 0018-05-03; is it possible to convert it to 2018/05/03?

Tags: r, date

The date in the dataset is a character date of "**18**-05-30". The date isn't seeing the full of year 2018 but instead it is seeing it as 0018.  I cannot change the dataset as it has alot of data to manually change.
I have used these codes below however they do not help much

```
lol2 <- (format(as.Date(Airbnb2$first_review, format = "%y"), "%d/%m/%Y"))
lol3 = as.Date(lol2)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4DR0.png)

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: can you please post a [mcve], i.e. show us `dput(head(Airbnb2$first_review))`? Please include both input *and output* as text rather than as images ...

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `format` argument in `as.Date()`. Using a tidyverse approach I would do the following

```
library(tidyverse)

# just some fake data using the same object/column names OP provided
Airbnb2 <- tibble(
  first_review = c('18-05-30', '18-05-31', '19-09-24')
)

Airbnb2 %>%
  mutate(lol2 = format(as.Date(first_review, format = '%y-%m-%d'), '%Y/%m/%d'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
lol2 <- (as.Date(Airbnb2$first_review, format ="%m/%d/%y"))

lol2
```